# Transitioning bootstrap's img-circle to img-rounded gradually

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

Is there a way to make an image change its class from img-circle to img-rounded not instantly but gradually via a mouse hover?

I understand it must be done via javascript/jquery since there is no other way to change a class of an object otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is both a CSS-only and a jQuery based solution. Code below, plus working example of both at http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/K52j4/:

jQuery

```
$(".js").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        "border-radius": "6px"
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        "border-radius": "500px"
    });
});​
```

CSS3 (no javascript necessary; works in Modern Browsers only)

```
img.css {
    -webkit-transition:border-radius 0.8s linear;
    -moz-transition:border-radius 0.8s linear;  
    -o-transition:border-radius 0.8s linear;      
    transition:border-radius 0.8s linear;  
}
    img.css:hover {  
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you can do this work with jquery,like to this:

```
$("img[class='img-circle']").hover(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("img-circle").addClass("img-rounded");
   },function(){
      $(this).removeClass("img-rounded").addClass("img-circle");
});
```

Comment: How does this address the requirement that the change happen "gradually"?